# printing a div of lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, css

well currently we have a requirement to print some part of component to be print 
  we have taken that printable data in a div now when we trying to print that

till before this we had gone through `window.print` too but it also not resolving

```
var divToPrint=component.find("printableDiv");
console.log('divToPrint.outerHTML: '+JSON.stringify(divToPrint.innerHTML));
newWin= window.open("");
newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
```

worked it also but no resolution can someone have workaround